# How to print an element of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, I want to print the element at the 2nd index of this array (3):
`int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Sorry if this is a trivial question, new to Java and programming in general.

Comment: `System.out.println(array[1]);`

Comment: To learn more about arrays, I suggest starting with the [Arrays tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: If you mean , you want to have a string instead of an int, you can use `Arrays.toString` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access elements of an array as `array[index]`:

```
System.out.println(array[1]);
```

Comment: Downvoter, explain what you do not like.

Comment: A question like that should either not be answered (but pointed to the duplicate), or, since the shared code is a pure syntax error, be corrected completely so that you produce runnable code.